# Jaydata with .net Odata Server

Tags: odata, cors, jaydata

I am working on jaydata as client and .net odata as server but when i request Server it gives me error of 501 not implemented and when i search out for it the issue was CORS [Cross Origion Resouse Sharing] is there any way to enable CORS on odata server or IIS  ???

my code is simple just create context with service and fetch entites one solution was to put specail config section in web.config

```
 <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </customHeaders>
 </httpProtocol>
```

But this does not solve the issue

[image: My Chrome View During the process]

Remember i am using odata [RESTFUL] service and jaydata as client

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because nothing handles the `OPTIONS` preflight requests. You'll want to intercept them. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19808069/2266481) on how to do that and [a few important notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19843014/2266481).

**Update:** The question I linked assumes a WCF Data Services implementation. If you're using something else, you'll have to edit your question or search for implementation-specific methods yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Use chrome dev tools or firebug or fiddler to see what is happening on the wire. Which browser do you use? Old IE can not handle CORS

Comment: Almost certain it's not a client issue.

Comment: odata requires certain headers so the server must allow those headers explicitly, I wrote a blogpost about it, see: http://jaydata.org/blog/misery-with-cors
you'll have to create a similar config for IIS

Comment: i have tried every solution available here on web but I am still getting the same error of 501 not implemented error